# MuleSoft and SQL Server DB connection failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, mule

I hope you all can help me, it's been 2 days WITH a MuleSoft(MS) Guru by my side and we cannot figure this issue out. Simply put, we cannot connect to a SQL Server database. I am using a `Generic_Database_Connectory` with the following information:

- URL: `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ba-crmdb01.ove.local:60520;Instance=CRM;user=rcapilli...`
- Driver Class Name: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

It's a `sqljdbc4.jar` file, the latest. The "test connection" works fine. No issues there. But when I run the app, I get this error (below)

Anyone been able to get a SQL Server DB connection to work???

```html
ERROR 2015-04-09 14:05:31,106 [pool-17-thread-1] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.DefaultDbConnection.isClosed(DefaultDbConnection.java:100) ~[mule-module-db-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.releaseConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:136) ~[mule-module-db-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:99) ~[mule-module-db-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver$1.process(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:164) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver$1.process(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:148) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.pollWith(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:147) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.poll(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:138) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:216) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:80) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1]
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_75]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_75]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_75]
```

Comment: Can you add your config? Are you running in anypoint studio or in a mule standalone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I used to configure and it works for me.. you can try this example :-

```
<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://ANIRBAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=MyDBName;user=sa;password=mypassword"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" />
```

and in Mule flow :-

```
<db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from table1]]></db:parameterized-query>
  </db:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your test connection works fine, there should be no issues with your DB connection. Please post you config XML and that will help identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There would be problem with you query string that you are trying to execute using the DB connector. As Mule connector test checks only the connectivity, not the correctness of your queries.

Did you tested your query ?? Are the value showing when you run this query in DB sql query editor?

if this not solves the issue then could you please share your flow with us.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, so i tried with different jar. You can get jdbc jar file from:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.1.0.jre8

Not very sure if the issue was of jar, but it worked after using this new jar file. Also, if you have mavenized your project, remove the existing sqljdbc jar file and its dependency from pom.xml file.