# Mule generic database connection.DefaultDbConnection:99 (null)

Tags: mule

flow:

```
<db:generic-config name="MS_SQL_DB" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:1433/myCRM_0813;instance=MYINST;username=sa;password=sa" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>    
<flow name="msconnFlow1" doc:name="msconnFlow1">
     <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${sfdcport}" path="msconnect" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <logger message="test---------" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     <db:select config-ref="MS_SQL_DB" doc:name="Database">
         <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from Account]]></db:parameterized-query>
     </db:select>
     <logger message="==done===" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

exception:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'test'                                       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-06-03 11:59:31,664 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: test---------
ERROR 2015-06-03 11:59:31,728 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.DefaultDbConnection:99 (null)
2. null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.DefaultDbConnection.isClosed(DefaultDbConnection.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.releaseConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:150)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:87)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Note: I am able to run same query with jdbc, and my test connection through studio shows connection success.

Comment: Even though studio shows a connection success, your connection string might be wrong. Can you replace the one you're using with something like: jdbc:sqlserver://host\instance:port;databaseName=dn_name. HTH.

Comment: when i do that, it says connection failed. I used same url in jdbc it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was having issue with port, finally given port no as

jdbc:sqlserver://host:49389;instance=MYINST;username=sa;password=sa.

Answer (score 0):

Use the driverClassName below:

**net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver**

Database url:

**jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:port/database**

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used to configure with MSSql server :-

```
 <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://ANIRBAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=MyDBName;user=sa;password=mypassword"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" />
```

And then :-

```
<db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from table1]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
```

And it works successfully ... [MuleSoft and SQL Server DB connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545942/mulesoft-and-sql-server-db-connection-failure)

Could you pls try the same